# Workbooks.open on a specific USB drive

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to know how to test a drive before openning it.
For example if the USB is on the E: or F:
Something like this :

```
if (?DriveExist?) 
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:"
else 
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:"
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do it:

```
Function driveexists(DriveName As String)
    Dim objDrv      As Object
    driveexists = False

    For Each objDrv In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").Drives
       If DriveName = objDrv.DriveLetter Then driveexists = True
    Next

    Set objDrv = Nothing
End Function
```

So you'd use it as

```
IF driveexists("F") then...
```

Comment: Very nice :) , +1

Comment: Nice, very helpful !